# Передача  параметра

Tags: post, javascript, html, ajax, php

Есть простая форма которая отправляет введённые данные на сервер:

```
<script language="JavaScript">
    var Gener=3.1232;
</script>
<form method="POST">
    Логин <input name="login" type="text"><br>
    <input name="submit" type="submit" value="Войти">
</form>
```

Но, помимо введённых данных, мне так же ещё нужно вместе с этими данными отправить на сервер сгенерированную javascript переменную Gener. Т.е. мне нужно, что бы по нажатию кнопки "войти" в массив на сервере попадало бы не только введённое login, но и сгенерированная javascript переменная Gener. Подскажите пожалуйста, как это сделать.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В форму добавь

```
<input type="hidden" name="gener" id="gener" />
```

Ис еще скрипт для заполнения расширь (можно jquery добавить):

```
$('#gener').val(Gener);
```

Comment: Чего-то не работает:
<?
 if(isset($_POST['submit']))
 {
     
   print $_POST['login'];
   print $_POST['gener'];
 }

?>

<script type="text/javascript">
 var Gener=3.1232;
 $('#gener').val(Gener);
</script>

<form method="POST">
<input type="hidden" name="gener" id="gener" />

Логин <input name="login" type="text"><br>

Пароль <input name="password" type="password"><br>

Не прикреплять к IP(не безопасно) <input type="checkbox" name="not_attach_ip"><br>

 <input name="submit" type="submit" value="Войти">

 </form>

Comment: Подскажите, пожалуйста, что я делаю не так.

Comment: А всё разобрался, спасибо.

Answer (score 0):

Может лучше сгенерировать в php и вставить в форму ?

```
<?
$gener = rand(0,1000); \\ тут генерируем $gener
echo '<input type="hidden" name="gener" value="'.$gener.'">';
?>
```

Comment: Нет, нужно именно с клиента отправить переменную, а не на сервере создавать. Просто она там на самом деле не генирируется случайным образом, а вычисляется исходя из данных находящихся на клиентской машине.(я написал здесь, что генерируется, просто, что бы не писать слишком много кода, и вопрос не стал бы слишком длинным)

Comment: понял. Ниже ответили на вопрос.